# SQL identity column with unique code column

Tags: sql-server, table

This seems a simple question but is it still necessary to include a primary key with identity even if my columns are only a unique code and its description?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
      column1 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
      column2 CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
      column3 VARCHAR(10) NULL 
      CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (column1),
      CONSTRAINT uq_column2 UNIQUE (column2)
)
```

Sample values:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('A', 'aaa')
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('B', 'bbb')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `column2` is immutable then it can serve as primary key. Only if it was to hold long values then you could consider to create a separate primary key field to save space in the tables that have a foreign key constraint with this table.